# Сила нажатия Enter влияет на ввод пароля для ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh

SSH. Подключаюсь. Предлагает ввести пароль. Копирую нужный пароль. Вставить. Жму Enter. "Отказано в доступе. Попробуйте ещё раз". Опять вставить, тот же скопированный пароль. Жму Enter увереннее. Заходит.

Что это такое? Как это можно объяснить и проверить?

Comment: Если входите через `telnet` клиента, то может быть из-за неустойчивой связи `enter` теряется, а когда нажимаете "уверенно" он вводится несколько раз и поэтому срабатывает?

Comment: @BarmaleyRedStar это только на одном сервере такое.

Comment: как учат в детских мультфильмах, если верить в себя, то всё получится... а если верить достаточно сильно, то ssh даже с неправильным паролем пускать начнёт...

Comment: Нет. Не влияет. Возможно что-то не такс вашим клиентом, а вообще хорошая практика, в плане безопасности, перейти на авторизацию по ключам.

Comment: А логи чё пишут?

Comment: Куча проблем может быть здесь за кадром, не описанных в вопросе. Самое очевидное спросить на чем вы работаете? - может быть проблема буффера, может быть проблема раскладки, может быть проблема клавиатуры, может быть проблема соединения, может быть проблема случайного нажатия чего либо, может быть плохой прогноз погоды наконец! Логи к такому знахарскому по кофейной гуще вопросу были бы кстати.